# Python requests session and cookies

Tags: python, web-scraping, cookies, python-requests

I am a lot confused about cookies.

I am trying to work out scraping with many post/get requests chained

And I notice that every step needs 'Cookie' evaluated in the headers dictionary, because passing the right dictionary is the only way I don't get any access errors.

However, I look always at my cookie jar (via .cookies method) as it was at the previous step, but I cannot find what I need for the current step. And I know that by inspecting the network data in my browser.

So how shall I build up step by step a chain like 1) login, 2) botton interaction for changing dates, 3) file downloading?

My fault is that I am using requests instead of selenium?

I already use requests.Session().... but this means that I don't need to show up Cookie field when sending headers? Either way (showing or not showing Cookie in headers) I get server access error AFTER having correctly logged in...

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

If you cant access your cookies probably the login credentials are stored in an HTTP Only cookies. This is a secure place to store them to prevent CSS attacks.

You should try using a requests [session](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) to send this cookies along with your future requests.

Comment: I alrrady use requests.Session().... but this means that I don't need to show up Cookie field when sending headers? Either way (showjng or not showing) I get server access error AFTER having correctly logged in